# how to copy a mysql database

Tags: mysql, copy

I have to get a copy of a MySQL database. I have all the access codes so I can connect to it.
I am tried searching.
How can I get a dump of the database so that I can install it onto another server?
Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this command

```
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

Ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: great - thanks - I looked at your link - bit beyond me really... do I just create a little php script, connect the offsite db and run it? Also, whilst I have all the access codes I can't get at the server where the db lives. I am connecting remotely

Comment: @maxelcat Sure .. `$ mysqldump -P 3306 -h [ip_address] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql`

Comment: @maxelcat You can try a mysql client if you don't want to mess with these commands `-->` try http://www.webyog.com/

Comment: got as far as this but it nothing seems to happen - like where's the file? <php exec('mysqldump --user=xxx --password=xxxx --host=xxx mm_db > mm_backup.sql'); ?>  It doesn't show me any errors, but also no file...

Comment: oh - just discovered that the file is sitting on my server ...

Comment: All sorted - thanks for your help